# Cloudfoundry Error uaac add user - Access Denied

Tags: cloud-foundry

I managed to install cf on aws ec2 followingthe guide http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/deploying-cf/ec2/

after some tryes, It seens that all be good with curl api.subdomain.domain/info

returning as expected.

Then I went to the next step, creating a user with this guide: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/managing-cf/managing-users.html

1 - executed:
uaac target uaa.[your-domain].com

got as response:
Context: admin, from client admin

2 - executed:
uaac token client get admin -s [admin-cliente-secret}
got:

Context: admin, from client admin

When i try to execute

uaac user add [test-user] -p [test-password] --emails [testemail]

I getting:
error response:

{
  "error": "access_denied",

"error_description": "Access is denied"

}

*Note that the brackets hold valid values

How can I fetch some info about this error, debug it in some way, or find out wath is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be a configuration problem.

Config your UAA configuration file like this.

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!starred/vcap-dev/y_qcaCczSVw
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!topic/vcap-dev/eaH4c2OmDEQ

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged on SO. It's better to include a synopsis of the solution as an answer. You can provide links for reference, too.